# How to display updated rows should come first with MySQL database and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with property details, I need to display the last updated properties first, not inserted.

Comment: Please comment down voter

Comment: describe more about your tables & question

Comment: Save a timestamp of when they were last updated. then `ORDER BY updated DESC`

Comment: I'am not the downvoter! What have you tried so far? Show your ddl.

Comment: @edCoder down vote ?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav You should comment before you down vote, then only I can improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `TimeOfUpdate` column and sort by that when displaying.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new field, assume its name to lastupdated

And then choose default as current_timestamp.

and then in your query use orderby

Just like thisone:

```
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

I hope it will work  for you

Answer (score 1):

just take one input field of timestamp and use attribute 'on update CURENT_TIMESTAMP' for it..
then use ORDER BY `column_name` DESC